Do I need to step-down the output of a charging circuit?
I am planning to use the Adafruit bq25185 to charge a 3.7v LiPo battery.
The bq25185 has a "Regulated 4.5V-max Load Output" so that I can use the device while charging. But the battery only outputs 3.7v - so will I potentially fry the device if I am using a 5v charger as input? How can I ensure I'm outputting 3.7v like the battery does?

The fully charged battery likely has a voltage more like 4.2 or 4.3 V.
